# WSO2 Cloud Services Gateway Agent is missing

Tags: wso2

I'm currently trying out WSO2 Cloud Services Gateway but I'm not able to see the "CSG Agent" option neither within WSO2 Application Server nor WSO2 ESB Management Console. Is there anything to do in order to have access to this feature?, I mean, any configuration, any feature/plugin/componente installation?

All documentation I read so far regarding WSO2 CSG seems to consider CSG Agent included in any "service hosting product" as a given. But unfortunately this is not my case. For your information, I'm trying with the following product versions:

- WSG Cloud Services Gateway 1.0.0
- Application Server 5.1.0
- ESB 4.7.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

-Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

CSG agent is no longer distributed with the Application Server, However it should be available with the ESB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Nadeesha, but I'm still not able to find the CSG Agent in the ESB (I'm currently working with the last version 4.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. I was originally trying to use ESB 4.7.0 with Cloud Gateway 1.0.0. I was having the same issue -- unable to locate/activate the CSG Agent. I eventually came across something that made we think I needed to use a Cloud Gateway and ESB based on the same Carbon version.

I downgraded the ESB from 4.7.0 to 4.6.0. The CSG was bundled as expected.